# Using simpleXmlElement, need to add 3 attributes to an element and the output element is missing namespace

Tags: php, xml

Im working to php SimpleXMLElement to build an xml sitemap and I have 2 questions about it.

As I'm working with a multilanguage domain I need to include the hreflang element see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en for reference.

This element has 3 attributes 'rel', 'href' & 'hreflang'.

How do we set this element and add custom values to it?

// example

```
foreach($array as $value ){

     $item->addChild('xhtml:link' , '//takes no value');

     // needed output
     <xhtml:link href="http://www.example.com/path-to-file" hreflang="de" rel="alternate"/>

}
```

Also when using

```
->addChild('xhtml:link')
```

it will output

```
 <link/> 

 and NOT 

 <xhtml:link/>
```

Yes im using the correct urlset attributes(xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml").

Answer (score 1):

When adding a new element using `addChild()` there is a third parameter for the namespace.  Also you add the attributes using - `addAttribute()`.  So create the element, then add each attribute one at a time...

```
foreach($array as $value ){
     $newElement = $item->addChild('link' , '//takes no value', 'xhtml');
     $newElement->addAttribute( "href", "http://www.example.com/path-to-file");
     $newElement->addAttribute( "hreflang", "de");
     $newElement->addAttribute( "rel", "alternate");
     // needed output
     //<xhtml:link href="http://www.example.com/path-to-file" hreflang="de" rel="alternate"/>

}
```